# node - execution context of callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, executioncontext

Hi i'm getting confused about the following execution context

```
let fs = require('fs');
let text;

fs.readFile('message.txt', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    text = contents;
}
console.log(text)
```

text is undefined outside the callback function..thanks!

Comment: i want to use text outside of the callback and store it in text globally

Comment: Understood, but that's not really how async functionality works.

Comment: ah the fs.readFile is async? ok that explains it :D

Comment: Precisely as the docs state: "Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file." If it wasn't, why would you need a callback function to do something with the contents?